# Using int vs bool

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking at some code, and I see a line that looks like this:

```
// 1 if timer is executing, else 0
private int _inTimer;
```

This appears to be a binary flag. You are either in the timer, or you're not.

**Why would you want to declare this as an int and not a bool?**

I can understand the scenario if you eventually want to add different states, but then I would argue using an enum.

Comment: Not all code is perfect ...

Comment: Is that field filled from an external source?

Comment: Maybe this was originally C code translated to C# or written by a programmer that often codes in C

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Would you still hesitate if it was declared as a string with non-trivial values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use `int` instead of `bool` if you need to use atomic operations such as [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583.aspx).

PS: I know about [`Interlocked.CompareExchange<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966.aspx), but it was introduced in .NET 3.5 and supports only reference types.

Comment: you totally nailed this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Only reason I can imagine for using `int` here - if more than one thing could be in timer at once. Verify it, and if this variable is not used as counter, than refactor this code immediately :)

Answer (score 4):

The person may not have known about `Boolean`.  Also, maybe there are more states being tracked with that `int` than is actually commented.

All that said, I agree, based on those comments in the code, I would have used a `bool`, and if more than 2 states were needed, I would have used an `Enum`, but again, I don't really know the implementation details of the code base you got that from.

Answer (score 1):

If it's intended to be used like a `bool`, use a `bool`. It will make it easier for other developers to understand the intention. An integer keeps no one away from assigning something higher than 1 and the bool is restricted to only using `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is no reason to use an `int` here, a `boolean` or `enum` would obviously be a better choice, but I wouldn't bother over such a small thing. I bet that there are more sweeping changes that can make the code better, instead of focusing on something small like this.